# PhotoImage won't Display in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview, ttkwidgets

I am trying to display an image in tkinter treeview. I have been reading possible solutions but none seems to work, I keep getting a blank tree only with the column heading. For what I have been reading, I have to keep a reference to the PhotoImage, but regardless of how much I try it just won't happen. A simple code example can be found below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk as itk
import PIL.Image
import io

s= tk.Tk()
s.title('No *£/**@#* image showing')
s.geometry('400x400')

s.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)

s.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

headings=['Image']

p = '032f8072.gif'
img1 = PIL.Image.open('032f8072.gif')
#img1 = img1.resize((10,10))
img = itk.PhotoImage(img1)

tree = ttk.Treeview(s)
tree.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='NSEW')
tree['columns']=headings
tree['show']='headings'
for i in headings:
    tree.heading(i,text=i)
    
tree.column(0, width=125,stretch=True)
#tree.column(1, width=125,stretch=True)

tree.insert('','end','0', open =True, image= img)
tree.image = img

s.mainloop()
```

I have tried with .gif and .png, i have tried with both PIL.Image and Imagetk.PhotoImage togeter and individually. I have also tried keeping img inside a list to be called from the list to avoid a missing reference.

I really need to get this small piece of code right and I am really frustrated with this little piece holding me back. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can create the columns using  tree['columns'], but as ne0n p1atypus say, you can't display them using tree['show']. You can still enter the name for the columns manually with explorer_tree.heading("#0",text="Image",anchor= 'center') note that '#0' refers to the column in which the image will be displayed. I didn't try entering the column name using for loop.
Also, when trying to construct a treeview to display images in different rows using a for loop, this algorithm has to be within the function that defines the treeview and all the PhotoImage objects must be append to a list to keep its reference, otherwise they'll be collected as garbage. I'll leave an example below.

````
    global eow
    global dffile
    global temp_result
    global explorer_tree
    #Define window and treeview
    explorer_headings = ["Name",'Code', 'Supplier Code']
    temp_list=[]
    
    eow= Toplevel(acm)
    eow.title('Stock Explorer')
    eow.geometry('400x650')
    eow.geometry("+0+0")
    eow.minsize(400,650)
    eow.state('zoomed')
                    
    eow.grab_set()
    
    #style
    style2 = ttk.Style()
    style2.theme_use("awdark")
    style2.configure("2style.Treeview.Heading",font=('Calibri', 18,'bold')) # Modify the font of the headings
    style2.configure("2style.Treeview", font=('Calibri', 20),rowheight=100)
    eow['bg']='black'
    
    #Columns and rows
    eow.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    eow.columnconfigure(1, weight =2)
    eow.columnconfigure(2, weight =2)
    eow.columnconfigure(3, weight =1)
    
    eow.rowconfigure(1, weight=4)
    eow.rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
    eow.rowconfigure(3, weight=2)
    eow.rowconfigure(4, weight=2)
    eow.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

    #Treeview to display data
    explorer_tree = ttk.Treeview(eow, style='2style.Treeview',height=3)
    explorer_tree.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='NSEW', columnspan=2, rowspan=2)

    #treeview scrollbars
    xscroll_file_data= tk.Scrollbar(eow, orient='horizontal', command= explorer_tree.xview)
    yscroll_file_data= tk.Scrollbar(eow, orient='vertical', command= explorer_tree.yview)
    xscroll_file_data.grid(column=1,row=5,sticky='NEW',columnspan=2)
    yscroll_file_data.grid(column=3,row=2,sticky='WNS',rowspan= 3)
    explorer_tree.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll_file_data.set)

    add_part_button = Button(eow, text='Add Part',font=('Calibri', 14,'bold'), 
                          activebackground='white', activeforeground='black',relief='raised', borderwidth=5
                            , command = add_part_from_pic_list)
    add_part_button.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky='NSEW', padx=100, pady=40)
    
    notfound_button = Button(eow, text='Part Not In List',font=('Calibri', 14,'bold'), 
                          activebackground='white', activeforeground='black',relief='raised', borderwidth=5)
    notfound_button.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky='NSEW', padx=100, pady=40)
    
    code_label = Label(eow, text='Code: '+str(code)+'  Name: '+online_name,background='black',
                       foreground='white',font=('Calibri', 18))
    code_label.grid(column=1,row=1, sticky = 'NSEW',pady=10, padx=20)
    #Name the headings
    explorer_tree['columns']=explorer_headings
    explorer_tree.heading("#0",text="Image",anchor= 'center')
    explorer_tree.heading(0,text="Name",anchor= 'center')
    explorer_tree.heading(1,text="Code",anchor= 'center')
    explorer_tree.heading(2,text="Supplier Code",anchor= 'center')
    #Format the columns
    explorer_tree.column('#0', width=130,stretch=False)
    explorer_tree.column(0,width=200, anchor='center',stretch=True)
    explorer_tree.column(1,width= 200, anchor='center', stretch=False)
    explorer_tree.column(2, anchor='center',stretch=False)

    explorer_tree.tag_configure('even',foreground='black',background='white')
    children = explorer_tree.get_children()

    eow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",Instant_exit)
    explorer_tree.bind("<Double-1>", add_part_from_pic_list)
#construct tree
    temp_list=[]
    for i in range(len(temp_result)):
        for j in range(len(dffile['Name'])):
            if temp_result[i] == dffile['Name'][j]:
                children1 = explorer_tree.get_children()
                temp_row = [dffile['Name'][j],dffile['Code'][j],dffile['Supplier Code'][j]]
                p = temp_row[1]+".png"
                pp = "images/"+temp_row[1]+".png"
                np = 'images/noimage.png'
                try:#Append the PhotoImage object to a list rather than to a variable This will avoid the image being collected as garbage
                  temp_list.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pp).resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)))
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    
                    temp_list.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(np).resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)))
                    continue
              
                if len(children1)%2 == 0: #When calling the image for tree.insert, call the image from the list i.e. temp_list[i]
                    explorer_tree.insert('','end',iid=(len(children1)), image=temp_list[i], values=(temp_row[0],temp_row[1],
                                        temp_row[2]),tags=('even'))

                else:
                    explorer_tree.insert('','end',iid=(len(children1)), image=temp_list[i], values=(temp_row[0], temp_row[1],
                                        temp_row[2]),tags=('odd'))    
    eow.mainloop() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This took awhile to figure out!  I eventually found this answer to a similar question from 10 months ago (not officially an answer but look in the comments under the question):
[Treeview Image not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256708/treeview-image-not-displaying)

The user said the comment solved their problem, so I tried applying it to your example.  What the commenter means is that the line `tree['show'] = 'headings'` forces the Treeview to only display the headings, and not the main body of the tree.  To fix this, replace that line with the following:

`tree['show'] = ('headings', 'tree')`

to show all of the tree, and the image should start showing up.

Comment: I found it too yesterday , but you where faster to post :) thank you very much though.  I solved another problem of images not showing when constructing a treeview using a for loop

Answer (score 0):

try this, for me worked.

```py
tree = ttk.Treeview(master=canvas, columns=car_header, show="tree headings", height=11)
img = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"frames/imgs/image.gif")
tree.insert(parent="",index="end",  image=img, text='Information', values=collection_tree[i], tags=('oddrow'))
tk.Label.image = img
```